# Why does my jQuery click function not work?

Tags: jquery, click, hide, show

I am trying to display a hidden div but it does not appear when the corresponding div is clicked. Could it be that the hierarchy is not properly done where I state the selector to be clicked? Here is my code:

```
$("#sub_projectLabel a li").click(function() {
        $("#h").show("slow");
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<ul id="sub_projectLabel">

                <a href="#"><li style="line-height: 10">Add Sub Project</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <!--<a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><h4>Sub Project Title</h4></li></a>-->

            </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping a listitem in a link is not valid html. do it this way:

```
 <ul id="sub_projectLabel">
   <li><a href="#">Sub Project Title</a></li>
 </ul>
```

and select it this way:

```
$("#sub_projectLabel li").click(function() {
   //do something
});
```

Comment: Ooh sorry I didn't include the other bit of html where I am using the h as an id to trigger the click function. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: was a bit confusing. As a sidenode, if you trigger your click with javascript, why do you use a <a>-link?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to show an element that does not exist. I see no "#h" in your HTML... are you wanting to target the h4 tags? If so, you would have to do it like this:

```
$("#sub_projectLabel a li").click(function () {
    $("h4").show("slow");
});
```

I would, however, also put the anchors inside of the list items.

Here a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ttV7D/

Comment: Hi. Nope I am not trying to target the h4 tag. If you read up a bit I commented that I left some of the html out by accident. I have a div wrapped around the content I want to show which has an id of #h. So I hid the content with a style="display: none" on the div inside the html so the jQuery should just activate the div when the corresponding selector is clicked to display the content of the hidden div. I think its just a hierarchy mistake with the html thats causing it not to work correctly.

Comment: Hi There. Well, there is nothing wrong with your click function so there must be a problem with the HTML. Hard to tell without seeing it though, can you post the missing code?

Alternatively you could test your HTML with the w3c validator tool [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/). If you have any invalid markup (like LIs wrapped in DIVs or Anchors) it should detect it.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the problem. It was the jquery-1.10.2.min.js missing the .js at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because there is no element with id="h". So your event listener works but you try to show something that does not exist.